# How do I read the names from a PE module's export table?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, pinvoke, pe-exports

I've successfully read a PE header from an unmanaged module loaded into memory by another process. What I'd like to do now is read the names of this module's exports. Basically, this is what I have so far (I've left out a majority of the PE parsing code, because I already know it works):

**Extensions**

```
public static IntPtr Increment(this IntPtr ptr, int amount)
{
    return new IntPtr(ptr.ToInt64() + amount);
}

public static T ToStruct<T>(this byte[] data)
{
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    T result = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
    handle.Free();
    return result;
}

public static byte[] ReadBytes(this Process process, IntPtr baseAddress, int size)
{
    int bytesRead;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
    Native.ReadProcessMemory(process.Handle, baseAddress, bytes, size, out bytesRead);
    return bytes;
}

public static T ReadStruct<T>(this Process process, IntPtr baseAddress)
{
    byte[] bytes = ReadBytes(process, baseAddress, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)));
    return bytes.ToStruct<T>();
}

public static string ReadString(this Process process, IntPtr baseAddress, int size)
{
    byte[] bytes = ReadBytes(process, baseAddress, size);
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
}
```

**GetExports()**

```
Native.IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY dataDirectory =
    NtHeaders.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[Native.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT];

if (dataDirectory.VirtualAddress > 0 && dataDirectory.Size > 0)
{
    Native.IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY exportDirectory =
        _process.ReadStruct<Native.IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY>(
            _baseAddress.Increment((int)dataDirectory.VirtualAddress));

    IntPtr namesAddress = _baseAddress.Increment((int)exportDirectory.AddressOfNames);
    IntPtr nameOrdinalsAddress = _baseAddress.Increment((int)exportDirectory.AddressOfNameOrdinals);
    IntPtr functionsAddress = _baseAddress.Increment((int)exportDirectory.AddressOfFunctions);

    for (int i = 0; i < exportDirectory.NumberOfFunctions; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_process.ReadString(namesAddress.Increment(i * 4), 64));
    }
}
```

When I run this, all I get is a pattern of double question marks, then completely random characters. I know the header is being read correctly, because the signatures are correct. The problem has to lie in the way that I'm iterating over the function list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code at [this link](http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2006/04/i-love-it-when-a-plan-comes-together.html) seems to suggest that the names and ordinals form a matched pair of arrays, counted up to NumberOfNames, and that the functions are separate.  So your loop may be iterating the wrong number of times, but that doesn't explain why you're seeing bad strings from the very beginning.

For just printing names, I'm having success with a loop like the one shown below.  I think the call to `ImageRvaToVa` may be what you need to get the correct strings?  However I don't know whether that function will work unless you've actually loaded the image by calling `MapAndLoad` -- that's what the documentation requests, and the mapping did not seem to work in some quick experiments I did using `LoadLibrary` instead.

Here's the pInvoke declaration:

```
    [DllImport("DbgHelp.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    public static extern IntPtr ImageRvaToVa(
        IntPtr NtHeaders,
        IntPtr Base,
        uint Rva,
        IntPtr LastRvaSection);
```

and here's my main loop:

```
               LOADED_IMAGE loadedImage = ...; // populated with MapAndLoad
               IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY* pIID = ...; // populated with ImageDirectoryEntryToData

                uint* pFuncNames = (uint*)
                    ImageRvaToVa(
                        loadedImage.FileHeader,
                        loadedImage.MappedAddress, 
                        pIID->AddressOfNames, 
                        IntPtr.Zero);

                for (uint i = 0; i < pIID->NumberOfNames; i++ )
                {
                    uint funcNameRVA = pFuncNames[i];
                    if (funcNameRVA != 0)
                    {
                        char* funcName =
                                (char*) (ImageRvaToVa(loadedImage.FileHeader,
                                   loadedImage.MappedAddress, 
                                   funcNameRVA, 
                                   IntPtr.Zero));
                        var name = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr) funcName);
                        Console.WriteLine("   funcName: {0}", name);
                    }
                }
```